# "git submodule status" does not see submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to update my submodule on a project in Windows 7, but Git does not respond to anything.

There is a `.gitmodules` file containing paths, etc.

When I run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` nothing happens. I don't get any output. Also `git submodule status` gives nothing.

When I try to add an existing submodule I get an error that it already exists.

It might be useful to mention that I am using 1.9.5.msysgit, which is the embedded Git version of SourceTree. The same problem appears with 2.6.1 or even 2.25.1 on Ubuntu Linux.

**Update:** Also SourceTree does not show the submodules either.

Comment: Does `git status` work? It may be a console issue.

Comment: Yes, it works just fine.

Comment: What's the output of `git status`

Comment: On branch branch-test   Your branch is up-to-date with ... nothing to commit...

Comment: I have updated git to version 2.6.1 and still the same.

Comment: So, to be clear, there are no files in the submodules?

Comment: It seems that there is a submodules directory, but it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what the problem was. The name of the submodule was not matching the path (based on the `.gitmodules`) and apparently if they don't match git does not recognize it.

So this is the correct

```
[submodule "lib/name"]
    path = lib/name
    url = ...
```

This is not

```
[submodule "lib/name1"]
    path = lib/name
    url = ...
```

I suppose someone created the `.gitmodules` manually, that's why I had this issue.

Comment: Your `.gitmodules` looks like that if you `git submodule add https://gitlab.com/some/name1.git` and you then rename it `git mv name1 name`.

Comment: In my case, submodule name and its path are the same. But the issue still appears and seems to be caused by something else.